# mkdir() fails with SD card although there is permission

Tags: android

I try to create a folder in sdcard

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "folder");
Log.d(TAG, "FOLDER :" +folder);
folder.mkdir();
```

mkdir always return false. I added permission to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I can create folder with `adb` tool.

Phone is Nexus 5 Android 6.0.1

what is wrong with code ?

Comment: Which version of android is running?

Comment: try folder.mkdirs() instead. also make sure you're asking for permission from the user since WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is considered dangerous

Comment: @MicheleLacorte version of phone is 6.0.1

Comment: @Zach also mkdirs() not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `android 6.0+` you have to request permission at runtime, so in `onCreate()` request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1);
```

And add this method (optional):

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
          if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted!        
            } else {

                // permission denied!
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied to write External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also [Nammu](https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Nammu) to check the permissions